# how to style price tags width fixed column product list in woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

i've been trying to style this for hours now with no luck.

i have set fixed column height in product list in woocommerce and i want to style the prices(sale and regular) to the bottom of it, one to the left and the other to the right.

i have used the following code:

```
a .price {
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 width:100%; }
ins.amount {
 position:relative;
 float:right;
 clear:both; }
del.amount {
 position:relative;
 clear:both; }
```

but they are styled one next to the other and not on the corners as i'd like them to.
i have also tried setting margins but they won't work good because not every price has the same amount of chars.
URL: http://men.trikaliotis.info
any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML as well. Without seeing the markup, that CSS means nothing.

Comment: you can see a live version at http://men.trikaliotis.info/wp/shop/

Comment: Please consider [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include the markup along with the CSS.

Comment: @PFlans i'm sorry but this is a woocommerce/wp installation so i can't exactly include the markup, instead i have posted a live version of the project. should i do something else?

Comment: Usually you'll get a better answer if you can recreate your markup and CSS in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). Try making `span.price { width: 100%; }` and setting `ins` to `float: right;` and `del` to `float: left;`. I don't think you need any of the clears.

Comment: You should use the child theme style.css to put all your CSS changes in. Otherwise your changes (like a .price) may not work.

Comment: @Gerard this is where i'm making all the changes

Comment: @PFlans unfortunately i cannot recreate the markup as it's an output of php/js combination. At least i don't know how to. i have placed what you said in css but the problem still persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below the CSS you need to apply. I also created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/s5rL16jn/).

```css
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .price {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.woocommerce ul.products li.product .price del {
  display:inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.woocommerce ul.products li.product .price ins {
  display:inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot you really helped me and i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is worth a try:

```
ins .amount {
position: absolute !important;
left: 0px;
bottom: 0;
}


del .amount {
position: absolute !important;
right: -120px!important;
bottom: 0;

}
```